# Pandas Left Merge / Join not Resulting in what is expected for left join

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge

So I may simply not be very informed on what a left join is, because I am getting tripped up... Here is my definition of a left join:

> Includes matched records from the left and right tables and unmatched records from the LEFT table in the output table.

Here is my example:

```
In[87]: df1 = DataFrame({'key': ['b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'], 'data1': range(6)})

In[88]: df2 = DataFrame({'key': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'd'], 'data2': range(5)})

In[89]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key', how='left')

Out[86]: 
    data1 key  data2
0       0   b      1
1       0   b      3
2       1   b      1
3       1   b      3
4       2   a      0
5       2   a      2
6       3   c    NaN
7       4   a      0
8       4   a      2
9       5   b      1
10      5   b      3
```

HOWEVER!!!  I expect to get this:

```
    data1 key  data2
0       0   b      1
1       1   b      1
2       2   a      0
3       3   c      NaN
4       4   a      0
5       5   b      1
```

My general thinking comes from Transactional data (such as accounting documents where I may be merging header and item detail, or merging lookup data).

What am I missing in my thinking or code to make this work?

PS - This comes from working through Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis book (page 179) - where he mentions the following:

> Many-to-many merges have well-defined though not necessarily intuitive behavior.  Many-to-many joins form the Cartesian product of the rows. Since there were 3 'b' rows in the left DataFrame and 2 in the right one, there are 6 'b' rows in the result.

I guess I am missing the point here?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. The first `b` in your first data frame, matches the `b` at position 1 and the `b` at position 3 in the second data frame. When doing the left join,  why do you expect only the first pairing but not the second?

Comment: Comes from my exp with a industry product [ACL](http://www.acl.com/).  My definition for this is 'Many-to-one joins match primary key values to the first occurrence only of a matching secondary key value. If additional occurrences of a matching secondary key value exist, they are ignored.'  I am hooked on this idea of the left table (primary) being unchanged and only brining in values for matches (but unmatched primaries remaining in the result with a NaN result - as it was unmatched).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to get your expected output is to groupby by `data1` and get the first value of each group:

```
g = df.groupby('data1').first().reset_index()
```

That returns:

```
   data1 key  data2
0      0   b      1
1      1   b      1
2      2   a      0
3      3   c    NaN
4      4   a      0
5      5   b      1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This requires calculating the full left join first. If speed is critical, this may not be an optimal solution.